# How do I connect to MSMQ (Microsoft Messaging Queue) from Android?

Tags: android, msmq

Hi I am trying to connect to a MSMQ from an Android phone. 
The problem is that all the libraries that I seem to find have to run in Windows since they appear to just be wrappers around C libraries ("DLL"). I found J-Integra but it seems like a very messy non-open source solution. Anybody has any ideas?

And does anybody know of a server in linux to host queues that I can install for testing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Step #1: Find some sort of Web service that interfaces with MSMQ

Step #2: Have Android work with the Web service

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend creating a WCF service that's RESTful and having Android interface with that using the HttpClient.