# Is it possible to connect to MSMQ from Android?

Tags: c#, android, client-server, msmq

Is it possible to connect to MSMQ from Android?
And hoy can I do it?

Comment: Why would you like to do such thing? Just build a thin HTTP service layer to serve the android device.

Comment: I have server, and I want this server to send messages to Android.Or is it better without MSMQ?

Comment: I don't think that exposing your Queue directly to the web is a good idea anyway. I'm not sure what exactly are you trying to achieve. Will each client will get different messages or all connected clients will get the same messages? I fell like you're heading the wrong way.

Comment: all connected clients will get the same messages

Comment: Just have a web server that the clients will connect to and it will fetch messages from the QUEUE.

Answer (score 2):

See [How do I connect to MSMQ (Microsoft Messaging Queue) from Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160240/how-do-i-connect-to-msmq-microsoft-messaging-queue-from-android):

Step #1: Find some sort of Web service that interfaces with MSMQ

Step #2: Have Android work with the Web service